# Получить список пользователей в контроллере

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Пытаюсь получить список пользователей в контроллере. Сначала пробовал так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался решить эту проблему (получить опции для создания контекста), получилось:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Comment: Проверьте код класса Startup по ссылке https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/3.2.php все ли у вас прописано корректно.

Answer (score 0):

> Имя "Configuration" не существует в текущем контексте

Это свойство находится в классе `Startup` (файл Startup.cs).

В этом классе в методе `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` зарегистрируйте ваш `UserContext`:

Startup.cs

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContextcontext context;

    public HomeController (ApplicationDbContextcontext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var users = context.Users.ToList();
        return View(users);
    }
}
```